# Is there a way I can extract a list from a javascript document?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

There is a website where I need to obtain the owners of this item from an online-game item and from research, I need to do some 'web scraping' to get this data. But, the information is in a Javascript document/code, **not an easily parseable HTML document** like bs4 shows I can easily extract information from. So, **I need to get a variable in this javascript document** (contains a list of owners of the item I'm looking at) and **make it into a usable list/json/string I can implement in my program**. Is there a way I can do this? if so, how can I?

I've attached an image of the variable I need when viewing the page source of the site I'm on.

My current code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://www.rolimons.com/item/1029025').content #the item webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
datas = soup.find_all("script")
print(data) #prints the sections of the website content that have ja
```

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLUpt.png)

Comment: where is your attached image?

Comment: Fixed, my apologies, I'm new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

To scrape javascript variable, can't use only `BeautifulSoup`. Regular expression (`re`) is required.

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert string representation of dict to a dict.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import ast

html = requests.get('https://www.rolimons.com/item/1029025').content #the item webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

ownership_data = re.search(r'ownership_data\s+=\s+.*;', soup.text).group(0)
ownership_data_dict = ast.literal_eval(ownership_data.split('=')[1].strip().replace(';', ''))
print(ownership_data_dict)
```

Output:

```
> {'id': 1029025, 'num_points': 1616, 'timestamps': [1491004800,
> 1491091200, 1491177600, 1491264000, 1491350400, 1491436800,
> 1491523200, 1491609600, 1491696000, 1491782400, 1491868800,
> 1491955200, 1492041600, 1492128000, 1492214400, 1492300800,
> 1492387200, 1492473600, 1492560000, 1492646400, 1492732800,
> 1492819200, ...}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" and when I print the "re.search(r'ownership_data\s+=\s+.*;', soup.text)" without the ".group(0)" it prints as None. Do you know what could be causing this problem? This should be line 9 on the code you put.

Comment: It works in my environment. Please check that you get response from requests correctly.

Comment: The only problem I can think of with our environments is when I don't have the "lxml" library installed [pip install lxml] I get the error "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?" Is this the one you have installed? With this one installed, I get my error described above.

Comment: let try `html.parser` instead --->  `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")`

Comment: Hmm, I changed that and nothing changed. I think the problem is happening in "soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")" because when I print that, it doesn't ever contain "ownership_data" or any data from what I see. (Even when I change that same thing happens)

Comment: Here's what it looks like: https://prnt.sc/22k8bvy it's just a lot of titles and some data with huge spaces between them.

Comment: If I do print(soup) or print(soup.contents) the ownership data shows up in the output if I scroll through the document enough but it still errors out at the same line as before with the error of "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: With group(0), still error ?

Comment: ownership_data = re.search(r'ownership_data\s+=\s+.*;', soup).group(0) | Still gets the error

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import json
import re

r = requests.get('...')
m = re.search(r'var history_data\s+=\s+(.*)', r.text)
print(json.loads(m.group(1)))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't (just) intended to solve the immediate problem, but (also) to help future readers understand the solution so that they can apply it to similar problems, or come to better understand the code. Given that, please don't just post code. Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe this is the best approach?